# Azure logic app standard connections ,parameters and appsettings

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-logic-app-standard

With azure logic apps standard we have appsettings where we can pretty much have any variable that can be referenced from connections.json and also from the logic app itself.

So with this, what is the actual use of parameters.json file with standard logic apps? we can refer and retrieve any values from appsettings right.
Can we totally remove parameter.json and refer any environment specific value from appsetting like how we deploy .net core apis?

As long as the devops pipelines deploy environment specific values to the appsettings then it should work right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you dont need to use parameters.json - appsetting does fine (even better because KV support)

but when deploying you need to make sure that parameters.json exists and contains a valid json afaik

Comment: Thanks viktorh for the reply. I did a quick PoC and it works without parameters.json after deploying to Azure so that tells me the the file itself is not mandatory as we have appsettings.